# What should I do add new table to existing database or make new database?

Tags: android, database

I am trying to write an android application. My application reads some information from database and shows it.

Now I  need to make the app personalizable for end users. For example, allow the end-user to bookmark a page or a line of text. For this what is the best idea for changing or modifing the database ?

Should I make new database and put a table for bookmark on that or add a table for that to my existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your use case and what you mean by "end user". If you intend for different users to be able to sign in on the same device, then you might create a separate database for each user. If that's not the case and the "end user" is really just whoever is using the device at that particular time (no authentication required), then you could simply add a table to your database.

Comment: No I just need my app install to their phone-cell or tablet and the database will copy to the phone when installed. is it  practical and suitable to have two database?

Answer (score 0):

Adding new database is something you will need to use if you want to access some data before logging-in by some user to your main database, so you don't need that! 
I prefer to add a table to your current database with a structure like this:

```
create table tblBookMark(
  Bookmark_ID int primary key,
  Bookmark_Name varchar(128),
  User_ID int --you can add a foreign key to users table here 
);
```

I hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need multiple database for a mobile application(never even heard of it). It will be unnecessary complexity for to simple a thing.

Multiple databases are normally used in scenarios where you have to store large amount of data from different sources and/or different physical locations for large applications.

Adding a table with proper structure(columns) should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

A Database Creation is not a necessity. You can just store the Table ID Value with respect to the BookMark and maybe store it in SharedPreferences. So you can access the information from the same Database based on the User Preference.